# Android project builds with gradle from command line, wont compile in studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

We have an app that was created by a external consulting company that I'm trying to make a change to. I can compile and create an apk by running the command

```
"gradlew clean build assembleDebug"
```

from the windows command line

But when I import it to Android studio, I'm unable to build or run from there. The error message is

```
Error:Android Source Generator: [myapp-android] AndroidManifest.xml file not found
```

The file exists, but is filled with errors such as

```
"cannot resolve symbol "@string/app_name"
validates resources references inside resource.xml files"
```

and so on.

The string.xml file with the definition exists at

```
myapp-android/myApp/MyApp/src/main/res/values
```

So, what do I do to get the gradle used by the Studio to see this? It looks like it's not recognizing the source directory - but when I mark it as source, then it doesn't see any android packages I try to import.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: @Satty That's not correct, `values` should always be under the `res` directory. @JackBeNimble can you post your build.gradle? Particularly the sourceSets closure?

Comment: ohh sorry. My mistake. I mean res Folder should be under  MyApp directly . Sorry again.

Comment: Are you sure about myApp/MyApp ?

Comment: Can you post some parts of your Gradle files?